# jquery css() in if else condition

Tags: jquery, css

What I'm trying to do is **IF** I click on a `span` then some elements in a `DIV` get faded out and **ELSE** you click again on that span those elements would get faded in. 
There I'm also using `css()` to change some styles of the elements remained in that `DIV` .

Look [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7G3Z4/6/) to check out the codes.

And now two questions/issues :

1. Is there some shortcut or technique by which the number of using `css()` could be lesser?
2. When I try to use `css()` in my `else` condition to take the style values to their original, none of them in my `else` condition work and therefore the new style values in `if` condition remain the same.

Any correction or  suggestion ?

Comment: That's not how `if.. else` works

Comment: Im not exactly sure what your goal is.. but you can group the css together like `.css({'width':'45px', 'height': '200px', 'overflow': 'hidden'})`, etc but again not sure what your end goal is...

Comment: It seems in your code, you're manually setting css properties *and* adding/removing classes even though you haven't defined those classes. Are the manual properties supposed to be what the class defines?

Comment: @zzzzBov, Can you point to where I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: @David Chase, My goal is to `fadeOut` some elements and change some styles using `if` condition and then using `else` condition to `fadeIn` those elements and change the style to their original.

Comment: @Lix, I've defined all classes. But I agree about css properties. not well-coded!

Comment: @John, `if..else` is a synchronous conditional statement, what you're trying to describe is an asynchronous animation. While you'd use `if..else` statements in the asynchronous callback, the way you've phrased what you're after is incongruous with the meaning of the words you've used in the context of JavaScript programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you could also just add a `class` to `#News` and apply all your styles in your CSS

```
#News.closed {
    height: 45px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#News.closed div {
    right: -10px;
}
#News.closed div label {
    font-size:12px;
    top: -14px;
}
}
#News.closed div label p {
    top: -15px;
    right: -20px;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/7G3Z4/10/

Comment: Thank you for the sample. Now I got what @zzzzBov tried to explain to me.

Answer (score 3):

> What I'm trying to do is **IF** I click on a `span`

**No.**  What you're trying to do is "*when* you click on a `span`..."

> then some elements in a `DIV` get faded out

...a `div` fades out.

> and **ELSE** you click again on that `span`

Have you ever heard anyone say "and else you click again"? If it's not how you speak, you shouldn't write it either.

What you're trying to describe is what happens when you click on the `span` a second time. It's actually not important how many times the `span` has been clicked on, what's important is the state of the `div`. What you're describing goes back to what happens when the span is clicked.

> those elements would get faded in.

So what you've tried to say so far is:

When you click on a span, check whether a `div` is visible; **if** it is, fade out, **else**, fade in.

> There I'm also using css() to change some styles of the elements remained in that `DIV`.

It sounds like what you're trying to say is that you're also styling the `div` using jQuery's `css` method. Given the state of the code this appears to (mostly) be the case.

**Don't use the `css` method**.

It's useful to use jQuery's `css` method when you absolutely require dynamic styles. Most of the time, most people don't need dynamic styles. Most of the time, most people need dynamic *sets* of styles. These are best represented as classes that should be left in stylesheets. HTML belongs in `.html` files, JS belongs in `.js` files, CSS belongs in `.css` files.

So what you really want is to change a class (or multiple) when the `div` has finished animating.

---

All of that without even writing any code. To tie it all together, here's generally what you'd want to do:

```
$('.some-span').on('click', function () {
    //when you click on a span
    var divIsVisible;
    //check whether a div is visible
    divIsVisible = $('.some-div').is(':visible');
    if (divIsVisible) {
        //if it is, fade out
        $('.some-div').fadeOut(function () {
            //when it's done fading out, add some classes
            $(this).addClass('is-hidden');
            //add other classes
        });
    } else {
        //else fade in
        $('.some-div').fadeIn(function () {
            //when it's done fading in, remove some classes
            $(this).removeClass('is-hidden');
            //remove other classes
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for going through details. And although I'm not an English-speaking person, I always try my best to speak English in the best manner I can.

Comment: And thank you again for the codes and the comments. Well-explained.

Answer (score 1):

To answer one part of your question :

You can set multiple css properties in a single call by passing an object (as mentioned by [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) -

```
$(elem).css({
  'width':10px,
  'height':10px,
  ...
});
```

Comment: so I've got to make an object using `var` ? any example ?

Comment: You don't have to declare an object with `var` - you can simply define it in an object literal as I did with my example.

Comment: OK. but if there are 3 elements and using them in `if` condition ?

Comment: Oh - yes, then it would make sense to create an object variable and pass the same one to multiple elements. Although... you can always pass multiple selectors and still use one literal object.

Comment: Though I need to go through some examples, I thank you for that point.

Comment: @Lix your answer is wrong - you can't use `10px` without quotes. Either use `10` or `'10px'`.

Comment: @dun - you are correct, however the code I give on the site is not usually fit for a copy and paste into someone's project... My example was to show a methodology and not to provide production code.

Comment: @Lix yeah that's fine. Just pointing it out for anyone who does try to copy and paste :)